# Where can I find the 5.2 valor point vendors?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have just started playing World of Warcraft again after a prolonged break (since very early in Pandaria) and there have been several major patches since I quit, including multiple new raid instances.

With this in mind, are there any new valor point vendors and if so, where can I find them? Do they require any particular reputation (like the 5.0 valor vendors)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can be found in Townlong Steppes. Check the map and you'll see an armor sign on the map.

And about the reputation: yes, the new Valor vendor also is linked to reputation requirement: The faction in question is 'Shado-Pan Assault'.

Feel free to check here yourself: [Ao Pye](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=70346/ao-pye)
[image]

Comment: There is also a vendor for 5.2 gear on the Isle of Thunder in the Shado Pan Assault Cave (near the entrance to Throne of Thunder).

Comment: @Ben - That's actually the 1st entrance, not _the_ entrance.  There's a second entrance to ToT past where Nalak spawns after your faction has unlocked the entire island.

Comment: Right, I'm not used to all the gates being open yet haha.